# Extruded SVG image in AR.js throws getUniforms of undefined error

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js, ar.js

I want to import a SVG file into my AR.js scene to be displayed on a marker.
For that I am using the official Three.js SVGLloader[1].

**While using this with pure Three.js I am able to load a SVG into my scene and display it.
But when I use the exact same function combined with AR.js I get this error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUniforms' of undefined
setProgram
https://localhost:3000/libs/three/example/vendor/three.js/build/three.js:24307:26
WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect
https://localhost:3000/libs/three/example/vendor/three.js/build/three.js:23313:18
renderObject
https://localhost:3000/libs/three/example/vendor/three.js/build/three.js:24041:11
renderObjects
https://localhost:3000/libs/three/example/vendor/three.js/build/three.js:24011:6
WebGLRenderer.render
https://localhost:3000/libs/three/example/vendor/three.js/build/three.js:23798:33
```

[1] https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/SVGLoader

My code is almost the same like in the example:

```
/ instantiate a loader
const loader = new SVGLoader();

// load a SVG resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'data/svgSample.svg',
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( data ) {

        const paths = data.paths;
        const group = new THREE.Group();

        for ( let i = 0; i < paths.length; i ++ ) {

            const path = paths[ i ];

            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                color: path.color,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                depthWrite: false
            } );

            const shapes = SVGLoader.createShapes( path );

            for ( let j = 0; j < shapes.length; j ++ ) {

                const shape = shapes[ j ];
                const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shape );
                const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                group.add( mesh );

            }

        }

        myMarker.add( group );  // add it to the predefined Marker, which works perfectly with other 3d Models but not with this SVG model.

    },
    // called when loading is in progresses
    function ( xhr ) {

        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened' );

    }
);
```